Hanging heavy mirror
What do I need to hang a really heavy mirror? It’s flat, so it would be right against the wall. It’s 40x60 and quite heavy. Hopefully someone sees this now so I can get it while I’m at the store 

We might need a bit more information: What is the mirror frame made of? What sort of wall are you hanging it on? Does the mirror have any mounting hardware on it?

Heavy stuff needs to be mounted to structural members of the house, wood studs/concrete.  You never think of using drywall anchors.  How the mirror is made, frame/frame less will matter also.

"40x60" what? Inches? Centimeters? Makes a big difference ...

what does really heavy mean? ... please edit your post with the weight of the mirror
